# Displaying table data through plsql procedure

Tags: plsql

I am trying to display the table info through this plsql code but when it executes the procedure it just show procedure successful. not the output.please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CarInfo
AS

V_serial                CAR.serial%TYPE;
V_Cid                   CAR.cid%TYPE;
V_make                  CAR.make%TYPE ;
V_model                 CAR.model%TYPE;
V_cyear                 CAR.cyear%TYPE;
V_color                 CAR.color%TYPE;
V_trim                  CAR.trim%TYPE;
V_enginetype            CAR.enginetype%TYPE;
V_purchinv              CAR.purchinv%TYPE;
V_purchdate             CAR.purchdate%TYPE;
V_purchfrom             CAR.purchfrom%TYPE;
V_purchcost             CAR.purchcost%TYPE;
V_freightcost           CAR.freightcost%TYPE;
V_totalcost             CAR.totalcost%TYPE;
V_listprice             CAR.listprice%TYPE;

BEGIN 
SELECT  serial, cid, make, model, cyear, color, trim, enginetype, purchinv, purchdate, purchfrom , purchcost, freightcost, 
        totalcost, listprice
    INTO  V_serial, V_cid, V_make, V_model, V_cyear, V_color, V_trim, V_enginetype, V_purchinv, V_purchdate, V_purchfrom , V_purchcost, V_freightcost, 
        V_totalcost, V_listprice 
    FROM CAR
    where cid is null;

Exception
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found')  ;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_serial||' ' || V_cid||' ' ||V_make||' ' ||V_model||' ' ||V_cyear||' ' ||V_color||' ' ||V_trim||' ' ||V_enginetype||' ' ||V_purchinv||' ' ||V_purchdate||' ' ||V_purchfrom ||' ' ||V_purchcost||' ' ||V_freightcost||' ' ||
        V_totalcost||' ' ||V_listprice);
END;
```

Comment: Your dbms_output statement is inside your exception. so unless there is an exception it will never print....  Also depending on what tool you are using you often have to enable DBMS_OUTPUT for each connection.  eg in SQLDeveloper you need to go through View Menu / DMBS_OUTPUT / click green plus select connection.

Comment: First - move the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_serial ...` above the EXCEPTION block, so that it's not in it. Second, before running this Procedure, execute `set serveroutput on;` in sqlplus.

Comment: Further, why use so many variables, when you can have just one? Have all the concatenations that you use in the last dbms_output in the select statement, then SELECT into a single variable and "dbms_output" only this one variable.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, I would write your procedure the following way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CarInfo
AS
l_result_clob clob;

BEGIN 
  SELECT serial   ||' ' || cid      ||' ' ||make      ||' ' ||model      ||' ' ||cyear||' ' ||
         color    ||' ' ||trim      ||' ' ||enginetype||' ' ||purchinv   ||' ' ||
         purchdate||' ' ||purchfrom ||' ' ||purchcost ||' ' ||freightcost||' ' ||totalcost||' ' ||listprice
    INTO l_result_clob 
    FROM CAR
   where cid is null;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_result_clob);

Exception
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found')  ;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE)  ;

END CarInfo;
```

*That is of course, if all the columns in the SELECT statement are actually convertible to character/clob, as Oracle would implicitly convert them, in order for the concatenation to happen.*

Cheers